# Powershell missing about_* help files after update

Tags: windows, powershell

After the recent windows 10 anniversary update nearly all of the about_* help files are are no longer in powershells get-help search path. update-help as an admin does not fix this issue either. I can see that they still exist but is there a way to add these back to the get-help path:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> help about_*

Name                              Category  Module                    Synopsis         
----                              --------  ------                    --------         
about_BeforeEach_AfterEach        HelpFile                            performed at t...
about_Mocking                     HelpFile                            Pester provide...
about_Pester                      HelpFile                            Pester is a BD...
about_should                      HelpFile                            Provides asser...
about_TestDrive                   HelpFile                            A PSDrive for ...
```

Here are the missing ones:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> dir $env:windir\system32\WindowsPowerShell -Recurse -filter *about*


  Directory: C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSWorkflow\en-US


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                  
----                -------------         ------ ----                                  
-a----        9/30/2016   3:24 PM          25897 about_ActivityCommonParameters.txt    
-a----        9/30/2016   3:24 PM           3128 about_Checkpoint-Workflow.txt         
-a----        9/30/2016   3:24 PM           3112 about_Foreach-Parallel.txt            
-a----        9/30/2016   3:24 PM           4123 about_InlineScript.txt                
-a----        9/30/2016   3:24 PM           1691 about_Parallel.txt                    
-a----        9/30/2016   3:24 PM           2833 about_Sequence.txt                    
-a----        9/30/2016   3:24 PM           4031 about_Suspend-Workflow.txt            
-a----        9/30/2016   3:24 PM          15250 about_WorkflowCommonParameters.txt    
-a----        9/30/2016   3:24 PM          10889 about_Workflows.txt  

 ...     and about 100 more in ...\v1.0\**
```

I tried using update-help -source directly on these files but that doesn't work either.

Comment: I think it's a known bug: https://powershell.org/forums/topic/powershell-missing-about_-help-topics-after-running-update-help/ - Microsoft missed packaging them up: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2028#issuecomment-246152335

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm.

Comment: @Marcus Check out [Install-AboutHelp](https://github.com/kilasuit/Install-AboutHelp) in the meantime